# Dynamically Add to Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Javascript object that looks like this.

`ips[ipID] = {}`

So I end up with a bunch of ips that need to store information that will look like

`ipID { name : 'val', anotherName : 'anotherVal' }`

My question is, how do I dynamically add these names and values?

Comment: I think you might be confusing JSON with Javascript.

Comment: JSON is javascript. I am just wondering how to add values to my object dynamically.

Comment: JSON is not Javascript, JSON is a data format.  The sample above would trigger an error in any standards complient JSON parser.

Comment: @mikerobi JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation, so I would say it's Javascript.

Comment: @WaleedKhan JSON has it's roots in JS, but it is not JS any more. Take a look at http://www.json.org/ it's used in other languages now, and is only a specification on how to structure data. Saying JSON is JavaScript because it has JavaScript in the name is like saying JavaScript is Java b/c it has Java in it's name...

Answer (score 48):

I believe this is the easiest thing to do if your names are dynamic:

```
var myobj = {};
var newFieldName = 'my new field name';
var newFieldValue = 'my new field value';
myobj[newFieldName] = newFieldValue;
```

Answer (score 27):

```
var ipID = {};
ipID.name = 'val';
ipID.anotherName = 'anotherVal';
```

Comment: Ok that works. I guess I should have mentioned that my names and values are both dynamic. So I am using tmp[name] = value; and then I need to add tmp.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to use the great underscore library (a swiss army knife for js developers), you could use the extend method http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend.

So for example

```
var tmp = { name: "asdf", val: "value" };
_(ips[ipID]).extend(tmp);
```

Hope this is clear, it would be easier to help if you had a more precise question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution For **JSON** Object:

By default:

```
array=[];
object={};
```

JSON Code:

```
var People= {};

Json.People[key]="value";
```

JSON Result:

```
{People: 
      {
        key: "value"
      }
}
```