# Dynamic Javascript Object creation

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How can I make  php array into Javascript object code?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically Add to Javascript Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071252/dynamically-add-to-javascript-object)

Comment: I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. This is how you dynamically name object properties and object values. I am assuming you want to build this dynamically where the property names are coming from a source. All you have to do is loop through the values

```
var treeData = {};
Loop Here
var nameProperty = "propertyName";
var nameValue = "propertyValue";
var childProperty = "child";
var childValue = {};
```

Try This.

http://jsfiddle.net/zKdMa/1/

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot. But I am still having a problem with the loop. How do I keep the hierarchical structure as shown in the original question. Do I increment 1++ every iteration. I am a bit confused? Can You Help? I would appreciate it:)